# Trying to upload image to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

Trying to upload image to firebase storage,
already added dependecies, storage is on public, no errors in logcat,
user authentification works perfectly

```
 private fun performRegister() {
        val email = email_edittext_register.text.toString()
        val password = password_edittext_register.text.toString()

        if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fill fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }
        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "email is " + email)
        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "password is $password")
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener

                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Succesfully created user with uid: ${it.result?.user?.uid}")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Faild to create user ${it.message}")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Faild to create user ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
    }
    private fun uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(){
        if(SelectedPhotoUri==null)return
        val filename=UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val ref=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$filename")
        ref.putFile(SelectedPhotoUri!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("Register","succesfuly uploaded image: ${it.metadata?.path}")
            }
    }
```

no errors in logcat

Comment: Please post full activity from Where your `uploadImageToFirebaseStorage` is called.

Comment: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener

                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Succesfully created user with uid: ${it.result?.user?.uid}")
                uploadImageToFirebaseStorage()
            }

Answer (score 3):

To get the image URI start activity for result. It will open an image picker:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
intent.type = "image/jpeg"
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true)
startActivityForResult(
   Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
   RC_PHOTO_PICKER
)
```

In onActivityResult check is it result from your image picker.

```
if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            pushPicture(data)
}
```

and at the end method to push the image to Firebase Storage:

```
    fun pushPicture(data: Intent?) {
        val selectedImageUri = data!!.data
        val imgageIdInStorage = selectedImageUri!!.lastPathSegment!! //here you can set whatever Id you need
        storageReference.child(imgageIdInStorage).putFile(selectedImageUri)
            .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                val urlTask = taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl
                urlTask.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                    //do sth with uri
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide him some explanation how you receiving data and what is `selectedImageUri!!.lastPathSegment!!`.

Comment: @Ashish It doesn't have to be `selectedImageUri!!.lastPathSegment!!`, it is a storage child Id, you can set whatever id you want.